# DropDownListFor: no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I just created my account on Stack overflow, so this is my first time asking a question: I have a problem with my DropDownList. I don't know what I am doing wrong, since I'm relatively new to ASP-NET and MVC 5, so please excuse any horrible things I did

Controller:

```
public ActionResult typeDevices()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> typelist = new List<SelectListItem>();
        DropDownModel type = new DropDownModel();


        type.TypeDevicesId = 1;
        type.TypeDevicesValue = "typeDevice1";

        typelist.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = type.TypeDevicesValue, Text = type.TypeDevicesId.ToString() });

        type.TypeDevicesId = 2;
        type.TypeDevicesValue = "typeDevice2";

        typelist.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = type.TypeDevicesValue, Text = type.TypeDevicesId.ToString() });

        type.TypeDevicesId = 3;
        type.TypeDevicesValue = "typeDevice3";

        typelist.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = type.TypeDevicesValue, Text = type.TypeDevicesId.ToString() });

        SelectList listvalues = new SelectList(typelist, "Text", "Value");
        ViewBag.DropDownValues = listvalues;
        ViewData["DropDownData"] = new SelectList(listvalues, "Text", "Value");
        return View();
    }
```

Model:

```
public class DropDownModel
{
    public int TypeDevicesId { get; set; }
    public string TypeDevicesValue { get; set; }
}
```

Index:

```
<p>
    <label class="field" for="Type">Type:</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("DropDownData", (SelectList)ViewBag.DropDownValues))
</p>
```

This code came from a video that I was following. [Link to video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9CJmLbnFko)

The error that I am getting is

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'DropDownData'

Comment: Creating a second identical `SelectList` from the first one is pointless extra overhead - its just `ViewBag.DropDownValue = typelist;` And you cannot bind a `<select>` to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` so `ViewData["DropDownData"] = new SelectList(listvalues, "Text", "Value");` makes no sense. Its `ViewData["DropDownData"] = 2;` if you want the 2nd option to be selected. But you code is awful practice and I recommend you read [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o)

Comment: thanks for the constructive criticism, I'll take a look :)
out of curiosity, if I want to take an item from a database, what should I do?

lets say the type_devices has a relation with the table computers_tabel.
and I want it to select the correct one that's related to the computer Id?

Comment: The link I gave you shows how to do it :)

Comment: alright, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved, I made a public actionResult TypeDevices but I never called to it. so that was kinda stupid. Thanks for the help everyone! :)

I fixed the problem by changing `Public ActionResult TypeDevices` to `Public void Type Devices` and called `TypeDevices();` in the ActionResult Index.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line of code

```
ViewBag.DropDownValues = listvalues;
```

to

```
ViewBag.DropDownValues = typelist;
```

you need to provide a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` type data to your dropdown. Your `listvalues` is of type `SelectList` but your `typelist` is of the required type.

Comment: Thanks but it didnt work, I'm still getting the error: Additional information: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'DropDownData'.

could it have something to do with the @Html.DropDownList("DropDownData"),maybe it should be DropDownValues?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ViewData["DropDownData"] = typelist;
@Html.DropDownList("DropDownData", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewData["DropDownData"])
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that didn't work also. I'm beginning to think that DropDownLists just don't like me :P

Comment: ViewData["DropDownData"] = typelist;

Comment: ViewData name and dropdownlist name must be same.like below 

@Html.DropDownList("DropDownData")

Comment: I tried that but I'll try it again.
It still gives me the same error : http://prntscr.com/dehf7x

Comment: yeah, the ViewData name and the dropdownlist name are the same.

Comment: Yeah dropdownlist doesn't like you.

Comment: And restart visual studio and pc.